# How to redraw canvas after OnSelectedChanged in Avalonia?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

In Avalonia 11 with MVVM toolkit, I have a  containing a  and . I would like to update the  when the SelectedItem on the grid change.The canvas should display specific drawing depending on the item selected, so I need to use c# (maybe in the code behind?) to draw everything.

So far I have been able to:

- Link the event in the ViewModel but I don't have access to the
- Access the  in the code behind but it's not link to the event

How to link the event in a place where I have access to the ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found so far is to create ObservableCollections for each of the shape I want to draw on my canvas and make a binding in the view. That is also more MVVM approach.

Here is an example for future readers that have the same problem:

```xml
<Canvas Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="100" Background="Yellow" Margin="3">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="{Binding Size}" Width="{Binding Size}" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="{Binding TopY}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```